# Server Application Eats Up CPU After 15 Minutes of Running

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, cpu

I coded a server application that constantly listens to data being sent to it. I took multi-threading into consideration by the way. I have the main thread, writer thread, and reader thread. When I launch the program, everything works perfectly. After about 15 minutes of up-time though, my CPU usage just randomly skyrockets. I believe it reaches about 40% just for the server application if I remember correctly. I think I'm doing something wrong with networking since this is my first time working with sockets.

This is what I use to read data:

```
public void run(){
    Socket s = null;
    InputStream in = null;

    while (Main.running){
        try {
            s = network.getServerSocket().accept();
            in = s.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (in != null){
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(in);
            try {
                while (input.available() != -1) {
                    byte type = input.readByte();
                    PacketIn packet = Utils.getPacket(main, type);
                    packet.readData(input);
                    if (packet instanceof PacketInLogin) {
                        PacketInLogin login = (PacketInLogin) packet;
                        login.setSocket(s);
                        String server = login.getServer();
                        Socket socket = login.getSocket();
                        Main.log("Login request from server: '" + server + "'. Authenticating...");
                        boolean auth = login.authenticate();
                        Main.log("Authentication test for server: '" + server + "' = " + (auth ? "PASSED" : "FAILED"));
                        if (auth) {
                            main.getServers().put(server, new DataBridgeServer(main, server, socket));
                        }
                        main.getTransmitter().sendPacket(new PacketOutAuthResult(main, auth), socket);
                    } else if (packet instanceof PacketInDisconnect) {
                        PacketInDisconnect disconnect = (PacketInDisconnect) packet;
                        main.getServers().remove(disconnect.getServer().getName());
                        Main.log("'" + disconnect.getServer().getName() + "' has disconnected from network.");
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e){
                if (!(e instanceof EOFException)){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } finally {
                if (in != null){
                    try {
                        in.close();
                    } catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    try {
        if (s != null) s.close();
        if (in != null) in.close();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is what I use to write data (to the client. This code is still part of the server):

```
public void run(){
    while (Main.running){
        if (!QUEUED.isEmpty()){
            PacketOut packet = (PacketOut) QUEUED.keySet().toArray()[0];
            Socket server = QUEUED.get(packet);
            DataOutputStream out = null;
            try {
                out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
                packet.send(out);
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (out != null){
                    try {
                        out.close();
                    } catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            QUEUED.remove(packet);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you have tested this multiple times and every time the CPU usage spikes after 15 minutes or so? Or is the spike random?

Comment: I can't see where you are closing the sockets / socket streams

Comment: @nhouser9 Yeah it always spikes about 15 minutes after launching

Comment: @StephenC I close everything upon exiting the application.

Comment: Well maybe you should close them earlier.  Without seeing / understanding your entire application, my suspicion is that it is leaking memory, sockets or threads and the "spike" is a consequence of the GC getting overactive.

Comment: I concur with Stephen C. Close your sockets and streams as early as you possibly can and see if things improve (they likely will).

Comment: @StephenC I updated the code above so that it closes the streams after reading/writing from/to them in a finally block but I keep getting a SocketException says the socket is closed. I can read 1 packet and send 1 packet only before the exception is thrown. Also, I check my memory usage and it seems like the memory is normal.

Comment: OK.  In that case you will need to provide an MCVE so that we can reproduce the behavior you are seeing and figure out what the cause is.  As it is, there is insufficient information ... especially if you are correct that this is not a leak.